# watin attach to manually started window keeps failing

Tags: c#, watin

```
IList<string> values = new List<string>();
var instance = Find.By("hwnd", "110CC");
    ...
if(instance != null)
{
   var ie = Browser.AttachTo<IE>(instance);
```

The browser instance is manually started by the tester in case this makes any difference.
This just doesn't work for me I keep getting an exception from watin saying that it can't find a window with that handle.
I got the handle with Spy++.
I tried searching by window title or window url also but it also didn't work.
Is there any way to do this?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The below works as expected / no errors.  WatiN 2.1, IE9, Win7

Before running the code, open an IE browser and point it at cnn.com

```
    IE browser = Browser.AttachTo<IE>(Find.ByUrl("www.cnn.com"));
    browser.TextField("hdr-search-box").TypeText("searchy");
```